# How to add a sparkline to Table or Matrix in PowerBI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, sparklines

In the Microsoft guide they say that you need to check a box in the preview feature settings in order to use a sparkline, but I can´t find this box to check.

I am using Version: 2.97.921.0 64-bit (September 2021)

[image: Preview Features]

Comment: Sept 2021 is a year old. You will need to update to a more recent release...

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 0):

It's here. Can you paste a screenshot of what you see along with a screenshot of your version of PBI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added a screenshot of what I can see.